# How to find difference between all integers in an array

Tags: python, numpy, loops

Can someone point me in the right direction to accomplish the following. I would really appreciate it.

Given the following column.

```
111
108
106
107
109
130
```

I would like to take the first number(111) and find and print the difference between the rest of the values in the order they appear.

I would then like to repeat the process starting on the second position(108) until all rows have looped through to the end.

And lastly I would like to display the biggest difference and row# from the results.

Expected output is something along these lines

```
Start bigest-difference row/positioning
111 19 5
108 22 5 
106 24 5
107 23 5
109 24 5
130 24 2
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: I've added the expected results. Thanks

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([111, 108, 106, 107, 109, 130])
data - data[:, None]
# array([[  0,  -3,  -5,  -4,  -2,  19],
#        [  3,   0,  -2,  -1,   1,  22],
#        [  5,   2,   0,   1,   3,  24],
#        [  4,   1,  -1,   0,   2,  23],
#        [  2,  -1,  -3,  -2,   0,  21],
#        [-19, -22, -24, -23, -21,   0]])
```

Comment: That works! Can I add something onto this. Anyway I can print the max/biggest difference between each column and the element# of that position?